# How remove certain member of list in dataframe that endswith certain string in python

Tags: python, dataframe, label, multilabel-classification

How remove certain member of list in dataframe that endswith certain string in python?
For example i have this table:

```
Text   |  label
=======================
text1  |  green txt,red,blue
text2  |  black,red,blue
text3  |  green txt,blue,black
text4  |  black,red,green
```

I want to remove the label that ends with string "txt", so the result i want to get is:

```
    Text   |  label
    =======================
    text1  |  red,blue
    text2  |  black,red,blue
    text3  |  blue,black
    text4  |  black,red,green
```

I'm sorry i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you want to remove are all strings. If your lists also contain other strings that you want to keep if they don't end with 'txt', then use the following:

```
df['label'] = df['label'].apply(lambda values: [val for val in values if not isinstance(val, str) or not val.endswith('txt')])
```

If the only strings that can occur in the list are those that end with 'txt' and all the other values you want to keep are not strings but integers, it is simpler:

```
df['label'] = df['label'].apply(lambda values: [val for val in values if not isinstance(val, str)])
```

EDIT:

Answer to the edited question:

```
df['label'] = df['label'].apply(lambda string: ','.join([word for word in string.split(',') if not word.rstrip(' ').endswith('txt')]))
```

Comment: i'm sorry i edited the question, actually my label is in sentence

Comment: Please be more precise with defining your problem. The fact that it is a sentence chances the approach. And it is still not clear what a member of that string is. Are the members seperated by the kommas? Why are there sometimes spaces after the comma and sometimes not. Are they important to keep or not? This is all relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that remove the item ending with 'txt' from a list and then call this function for each value of `label`.

```
def fun(row):
    ret_list=[]
    for item in str(row).split(','):
        if not str(item).endswith('txt'):
            ret_list.append(item)
    return ','.join(ret_list)

df['label']=[fun(x) for x in df.label.values]
```

Comment: i'm sorry i edited the question, actually my label is in sentence